# how to specify HttpSettings@socket_timeout in commandline in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

I am using SoapUI and wondering if is it possible to specify HttpSettings@socket_timeout in command line..?

m using ant target to execute my test cases something like

```
<exec executable="cmd">
         <arg value="/c"/>
         <arg value="testrunner.bat"/>
         <arg value="-e${test.server}"/>
         <arg value="-s${test.suite}"/>
         <arg value="-r"/>
         <arg value="-a"/>
         <arg value="-j"/>         
         <arg value="-f${test.report}"/>
         <arg value="${soapui.project.file}/>               
</exec>
```

can i add something like : `<arg value="-GHttpSettings.socket_timeout=2000"/>`
i believe -g is for global settings with property.name=value

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that -G is the syntax for setting global parameter values via command line, but I have not had any success getting the command line to accept a new socket_timeout value. Granted, I'm executing the tests by calling testrunner.bat in a Jenkins job, but the command-line argument syntax should be the same.

None of the following worked for me:

- -GHttpSettings.socket_timeout=2000
- -GHttpSettings@socket_timeout=2000
- -Gsocket_timeout=2000

The only way I can get command-line SoapUI to accept a custom value for socket timeout is to set the value in the soapui-settings.xml for the user that is executing the tests. In Windows-based testing environment, this file is located at C:\Users\MyUserName\soapui-settings.xml. Here are the contents of my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-settings xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
<con:setting id="HttpSettings@socket_timeout">2000</con:setting>
</con:soapui-settings>
```

If using the soapui-settings.xml file is a reasonable approach in your case, this should work for you.